# if $M$ is a monoid then $a \in M$ is invertible iff $\exists b \in M: \text{ } aba=a \text{ and } ab^2a=e$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Apparently this should be an easy question, but I couldn't solve it on my own. I used the search option on MSE and I don't think a similar question has been asked before.

Suppose that $(M,\star)$ is a monoid and $a \in M$.

Show that $a$ is an invertible element of $M$ if and only if

$\exists b \in M: \text{ } aba=a \text{ and } ab^2a=e$.

I attempted to show that $ab^2=b^2a$ is the inverse element that we are looking for, but I failed to establish the equality between $ab^2$ and $b^2a$. I have a gut feeling that first I must examine if $ab=ba=e$ is true but I have no idea how to prove this equality either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see here:

$$ab=abab^2a=ab^2a=e$$

Try the other direction for yourself :)

Comment: Thanks. I hate it when I have the right idea in mind but I fail to spot the starting point.. :(

Comment: @some1.new4u Happens to us all :) I just figured this out by seeing what, if $a$ was invertible $b$ would need to be. The first equation told me that $b=a^{-1}$. I then just wrote $ab$ with the goal of getting $e$, and then started using identites.

Comment: Yes, I also did the same, but I was dumb enough not to write down $ab= \cdots$ on the paper and see whether it is really equal to $e$ or not. By the way, in the language of semi-groups, do they call $a$ regular if there exists a $b$ such that $aba=a$?

Comment: @some1.new4u Yes, that seems right. At least it's consistent with the terminology for Von Neumann regular rings.